# Fatal error come when using TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

when using  TCPDF
it  show following  fatal  error

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 8388608 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16 bytes) in D:\wamp\www\tcpdf\unicode_data.php on line 7833
```

how i fix that error-
my php version is PHP version :5.2.5
Apache version :Apache/2.2.6 (Win32)

Comment: This means that the process is trying to consume more memory that is allowed ... the `php.ini` specifies how much memory you can consume

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means that 8 Mb of RAM isn't enough for your PHP script, that generate PDF file.

Go to your php.ini, find "memory_limit" and change that line to something like that:

```
memory_limit = 256M;
```

After that, restart your Apache.

Comment: 8388608 bytes are 8 MB ;-)

Comment: after change it like   memory_limit = 256M      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (8MB) again come same error